# scaler.inverse_transform() is giving an error while taking LSTM NN predictions into real data values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have converted my data between 0 and 1 and fed it via LSTM NN .The  results also stay between 0 and 1 and to have the proper output i need to convert it back to as it was same with my original data values.

But

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaler.inverse_transform(result)
```

outputs an error . My code is as below. Here i have loaded saved Data,Target & LSTM trained Weights.

```
import numpy as np

data=np.load('data_2.npy')
target=np.load('target_2.npy')
train_data=data[:120]
train_target=target[:120]

test_data=data[120:]
test_target=target[120:]

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense,Dropout

model=Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=172,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(data.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=940,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=2510,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.load_weights('AirlineLSTMweights.h5')

result=model.predict(test_data)
print(result)


scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaler.inverse_transform(result)
```

NotFittedError: This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Can anyone help me here please?

```
my print(results) = [[0.6232013 ]
 [0.67273337]
 [0.7892405 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just what the error is saying. when using scikit-learn modules, they usually have a fit(), transform(), or in case of classifiers also predict() methods. after making an instance of a Class like MinMaxScaler() in your case, you need to fit it on some data, just call its fit method and pass your training examples as an argument. in your code here, you made an instance, but it does not know what your data was to update its internal variables which it uses when you call its transform, or inverse_transform.

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train) # you missed this line
# rest of your code for training Neural network with x_train
...
# now convert the result
scaler.inverse_transform(result)
```

scikit-learn [Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html?highlight=minmaxscaler) is the best Documentation you ever see, check it out if you still felt stuck.

Comment: Please explain me further. Here i have feed data after converting it witing range 0 and 1 for NN. my NN gives results also lay between 0 and 1. I need to feed that output to inverse transform and take outputs as to compare with real data set.

Comment: I edited my answer. also click on the Doc link to go to the MinMaxScaler doc page.

Comment: Dear Leo, Yes it worked. The error was with that i did not fit the target data to MinMaxScaler first. Since in my NN i have used pre prepared data and targets which were scaled early using scaler fit function,here i was only expected NN result to inverse transform and its totally wrong. So now i have feed the relevant origianl  target data to scaler.fit and then call scaler.inverse and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: glad it worked. please select my answer as accepted one. whenever you ask a question and someone answer's helps you, the protocol here is to accept the answer as it is a way to gain reputation in SO.

Comment: Tell me how to do that?

Comment: there must be a tick mark left side of my answer, where there is two up vote and downvote arrow. click that.